# xamarin android : resource does not contain a definition for 'style'

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

im trying to add animation into my android dialog fragment , i have created style.xml into values folder but i got this error: resource does not contain a definition for style.

```
public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Dialog.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
        base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Dialog.Window.Attributes.WindowAnimations = Resource.style.dialoge_animation;
    }
```

style.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
<style name="dialoge_animation">
<item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@animation/slide up</item>
<item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@animation/slide_right</item>
 </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: First of all, make sure your style which is created in the styles.xml file with the build action `AndroidResource` is correct, then you can try rebuild your project, then this `Resource.Style` will show up.

Comment: @GraceFeng-MSFT i dont get your idea where i should check AndroidResource ?